# What are the ways to make an html link open a folder

Tags: html, directory, hyperlink

I need to let users of an application open a folder by clicking a link inside a web page. The path of the folder is on the network and can be accessed from everywhere. I'm probably sure there is no easy way to do this, but maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: I've answered below; this is a common requirement of enterprise web applications that is made nearly impossible by misguided security (it should be possible to enable file links in trusted http pages). I have only tested extensively on Windows.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Do you want to open a shared folder in Windows Explorer? You need to use a `file:` link, but there are caveats:

- Internet Explorer will work if the link is a converted UNC path (`file://server/share/folder/`).
- Firefox will work if the link is in its own mangled form using five slashes (`file://///server/share/folder`) **and** the user has [disabled the security restriction on `file:` links in a page served over HTTP](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work). Thankfully IE also accepts the mangled link form.
- Opera, Safari and Chrome can not be convinced to open a `file:` link in a page served over HTTP.

Comment: in IE only if the UNC path and the website containing the link are in the same domain, that is to say only in the intranet.

Comment: I think this is no longer correct - newer versions of IE seem to block this behavior just as Chrome/Safari/etc.

Comment: I just tried this in IE 11 and you can in fact open a local file without downloading it (as in open an already existing file path). This still does not exist in chrome.

Comment: You can get this to work in Chrome via  [LocalLinks Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) . Thanks to [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2436256/1181012)

Comment: @Andrew Duffy, is there any kind of documentation that says Google Chrome is blocking this behavior ? I would like to know more about this

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2199283/revisions) seems to give a slightly different answer.

Comment: @Andrew Duffy, Is it possible to open a file present in the local machine with a relative path?

Answer (score 9):

The URL `file://[servername]/[sharename]` should open an explorer window to the shared folder on the network.

Comment: Is it possible to open a file present in the local machine with a relative path?

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the party, but I had to solve this for myself recently, though slightly different, it might still help someone with similar circumstances to my own.

I'm using xampp on a laptop to run a purely local website app on windows. (A very specific environment I know). In this instance, I use a html link to a php file and run:

```
shell_exec('cd C:\path\to\file');
shell_exec('start .');
```

This opens a local Windows explorer window.

Comment: Promising, but when I run this in Firefox the tab hangs.  (Seems to be churning the session or something, because I can access other sites, but this site seems to be hung -- even in other tabs!)

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox, it works for me, but I can't specify the folder in which to open, it only opens in the root directory of the php file.

Comment: @LucasTaulealea I wonder why this answer has not been upvoted more. I would just add a little correction: the `cd` part seems unnecessary, in my case using only `shell_exec('start C:\path\to\file');` works and supports both a folder or file

Comment: @Kaddah It probably hasn't been upvoted more because this solution only works when the webserver is running on the same computer as your web browser.  Most people are probably looking for ways to serve Windows Share Files from a corporate network web site.

Comment: I got it working with this function called by a route. (using it only on local env)
```
public function openFolder(Media $media)
    {
        shell_exec('start C:/laragon/www/project_abc/storage/app/public/' . $media->path);
        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Using file:///// just doesn't work if security settings are set to even a moderate level.

If you just want users to be able to download/view files* located on a network or share you can set up a Virtual Directory in IIS. On the Properties tab make sure the "A share located on another computer" is selected and the "Connect as..." is an account that can see the network location.

Link to the virtual directory from your webpage (e.g. http://yoursite/yourvirtualdir/) and this will open up a view of the directory in the web browser.

*You can allow write permissions on the virtual directory to allow users to add files but not tried it and assume network permissions would override this setting.

Comment: This is relevant today, as Chrome and newer versions of IE will block access to local file:// resources from non-file web pages. Additionally, this can be setup to run in IIS Express, although it must be added and run manually.

Answer (score 5):

make sure your folder permissions are set so that a directory listing is allowed then just point your anchor to that folder using chmod 701 (that might be risky though)
for example

```
<a href="./downloads/folder_i_want_to_display/" >Go to downloads page</a>
```

make sure that you have no index.html any index file on that directory

Comment: This answer works. The "directory listing allowed" part is very important. If it's not allowed, you can enabled it but it's different for every server application.

Comment: Is it possible to open a file present in the local machine with a relative path using an anchor tag?

Answer (score 5):

What I resolved doing is installing a local web service on every person's computer that listens on port `9999` for example and opens a directory locally when told to.  My example node.js express app:

```
import { createServer, Server } from "http";

// server
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

// other
import util from 'util';
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

export class EdsHelper {
    debug: boolean = true;
    port: number = 9999
    app: express.Application;
    server: Server;

    constructor() {
        // create app
        this.app = express();
        this.app.use(cors());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            extended: true
        }));

        // create server
        this.server = createServer(this.app);

        // setup server
        this.setup_routes();
        this.listen();
        console.info("server initialized");
    }

    private setup_routes(): void {
        this.app.post("/open_dir", async (req: any, res: any) => {
            try {
                if (this.debug) {
                    console.debug("open_dir");
                }

                // get path
                // C:\Users\ADunsmoor\Documents
                const path: string = req.body.path;

                // execute command
                const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`start "" "${path}"`, {
                    // detached: true,
                    // stdio: "ignore",
                    //windowsHide: true,    // causes directory not to open sometimes?
                });

                if (stderr) {
                    throw stderr;
                } else {
                    // return OK
                    res.status(200).send({});
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("open_dir >> error = " + error);
                res.status(500).send(error);
            }
        });
    }

    private listen(): void {
        this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.info("Running server on port " + this.port.toString());
        });
    }

    public getApp(): express.Application {
        return this.app;
    }

}
```

It is important to run this service as the local user and not as administrator, the directory may never open otherwise.
Make a POST request from your web app to localhost: `http://localhost:9999/open_dir`, data: `{ "path": "C:\Users\ADunsmoor\Documents" }`.

Answer (score 3):

Does not work in Chrome, but this other answers suggests a solution via a plugin:

[Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

Answer (score 3):

You can also copy the link address and paste it in a new window to get around the security. This works in chrome and firefox but you may have to add slashes in firefox.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for **File System Access API** and ended up in this question.

I know that API doesn't allow one to open an **html link** to a folder, but it does **allow for opening local folders and files**. For more information, take a look here:

https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will help someone someday. I was making a small POC and came across this.
A button, onClick display contents of the folder. Below is the HTML,

```
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='file:///C:/Users/' " value='Users'>
```

Comment: Chrome gives me an error: Not allowed to load local resource: <URL>

Comment: @Dave Sottimano I tested it just now. Works for me in Google Chrome, Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: this just downloads the file for me, vs running it in its native app