# XMLHttpRequest not working (blank page)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I copied this code from W3Schools (along with the original XML file cd_catalog.xml) and I'm getting a blank page:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried Opera, Firefox, IE and Chrome.
Nothing. :(

Comment: How are you serving this?  I am thinking your cd_catalog.xml can't be found...

Comment: Are you using a webserver, or accessing it via a file URL like file:///C:/test/test.html.  The latter might be a problem.

Comment: What do you get if you try `console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML)`?

Comment: I am not using a web server. cd_catalog.xml is located in C:/ (the same directory where the cd_catalog.html file is located). I tried console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML) but I still get a blank screen. :(

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not using a web server try doing this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///C:/cd_catalog.xml", false);
```

You may end up needing a web server because the browsers will not allow your script access to the local files, e.g. see discussion here:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=233306

So consider setting up a simple web server on your machine, like [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).

EDIT: the way I interpret the spec ( http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-open%28%29-method ) is that this must be done through HTTP.  It's not absolutely clear though. A file: URL may not be allowed in this context so the expectation is that the code snippet above may not work and you will **need** a web server.

A related question is:

[Read file:// URLs in IE XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142156/read-file-urls-in-ie-xmlhttprequest)

and

[Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

Comment: Tried the file thing, didn't work in either browser.

This is the error message I'm getting (Chrome console):

1)XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/cd_catalog.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
2)Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 cd_catalog.html:14

Anyways, I guess I'll try running it from WAMP or something.

Comment: There are lots of options for web servers that you can set up pretty easily.  Looks like you need one.  Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain

Answer (score 2):

Upload your code to a web server. You will get the desired output on all browsers such as IE, Chrome, or Mozilla. But if you try this same code on the local machine, then IE and Chrome won't work.