# How do you open a file folder through a link on website in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, file-io, directory

I'm working on a web application that needs to have a link which opens a documents folder from a file server. The folder can be opened either in a new browser tab or new window, or using the computer's default file browser program (i.e. Windows Explorer). This javascript should do the trick:

`window.open('file://///fileserver.companyname/public/Documents/','_blank);`

and this html should also work:

`<a href="file://///fileserver.companyname/public/Documents/">Open Documents</a>`

but these both only work in Internet Explorer, and our users always use Firefox and Chrome. Apparently the default security settings for Firefox and Chrome don't let you open a "file://" when the request is called from an "http://" website.

I've seen several references to this page: [Links to local pages do not work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work) which describes why you can't open files from webpages using Firefox and offers a few workarounds. Unfortunately, it only offers two options: install a plug-in on each browser instance, or create a user preferences file for each browser instance. Neither of these options are acceptable because we have too many users. The company I work for is not willing to apply anything to each machine which needs to access this link. Aside from that, I tried both plug-ins and the preferences file anyway, and the only one that worked for me was the IE Tab plug-in. I think the reason LocalLinks didn't work is because I'm trying to open a folder, not a file.

This stackoverflow question described similar options for Chrome: [Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links) but again, the LocalLinks plug-in didn't work for me and plug-ins aren't acceptable anyway.

I also found a website that suggested to use a command line argument top open files in Chrome (http://www.askyb.com/chrome/open-local-file-in-google-chrome/) and one that showed how to apply the argument automatically (https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/making-google-chrome-option-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent), but if I read it correctly it still involves applying changes to every computer accessing our website.

Is there *any* way to **open a file folder** in both **Firefox and Chrome** entirely **programmatically** i.e. within my web application C# or Javascript code without installing a plug-in or adding a preferences file to individual computers? I cannot alter any of these business requirements.

*Sidenote*: We are using C# with MVC 4. I would prefer to open the folder using a Controller Action in C# (because I'd like to create the folder before opening it if it doesn't exist yet), but javascript or html on the client side is acceptable. For Internet Explorer, I can create that javascript in the C# code by wrapping it in the JavaScript( ... ) function built into MVC C# Controllers. When testing IE Tabs in Firefox and Chrome, I had to define it as an href link, not a function that opens a window, or IE Tabs wouldn't recognize it as a link. But neither of these were acceptable workarounds for our business needs.

Comment: I suspect that, if what you're describing is possible, it would represent a security hole.

Answer (score 2):

The request was dropped before I could come up with a feasible solution, but in case anyone else is still struggling with this problem I will describe workaround that would not require any workstation customization.

They don't technically need to use the built-in file explorer to open a folder. Instead, a creative way to display the information the business wanted without breaking any browser security rules would be to iterate though the files without opening the file explorer and then display a list of folders/files in a browser window.

Using [Directory.EnumerateDirectories(filepath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Directory.EnumerateFiles(filepath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can get a list of folders and files to display. When the user clicks one of the folders, call these methods again to get the next level of folders and filenames. When the user clicks a file, download/open it. These methods return the folder and file names as lists of strings, so you would just need to render the lists with custom icons in the browser. (The methods are from C#'s System.IO library.)

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple html code:

`<input type="file" webkitdirectory>`

but the problem with this code is that it works only on google!