# Open local folder from different browsers

Tags: c#, browser, hyperlink, local

I'm developing an intranet (written in c#) and I need to access some local folders (stored in an internal server) using local links.

I actually tried to use "\server-name\folder-name$" as link and it works fine on Internet Explorer. If used on Chrome though, nothing happens; worse on Firefox, where I get the 404 error message.

I also tried to change the link (as seen in many posts here) in "file://server-name/folder-name$" or "file://///server-name/folder-name$", always working on IE, but nothing's happening on Firefox and Chrome.

I'm looking for a simple solution that would work for at least these 3 browsers, if possible..

I tried to follow some workarounds, especially [HERE](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work) but it's not what I'm looking for. I'd rather not installing extensions nor edit some particular settings (don't know why the process for Firefox didn't work), if possible!

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A tip: if something works only on internet explorer, it shouldn't work at all, and you're approaching it from the wrong angle.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you attempting to open up and navigate folders and simulate Windows Explorer? In the context of the client user or the web app's user?

Comment: have you tried to prefix your link by [file:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: A website that could open local folders? Oh dear, that would be something! Seriously, don't do that. Period.

Comment: Yeah the idea is to open folders and access files..like in Windows Explorer. Only those who have access to the domain can access my intranet (and these local links as well). Is there another way to do it? I don't want just a copy of those files and folders..people should be able to edit them directly if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the only browser that allows local links is Internet Explorer.

It's been removed from other browsers because of the security holes it provides. [Here's a relevant SO post about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

With that being said, I think some extensions [change Google Chrome to allow this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida). I don't know of any that do this for Firefox.

**EDIT**: It's [possible on Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/).

This may not be that helpful though, since you're developing the intranet and presumably won't be the only one using it.

Comment: I've installed the Firefox add-on you gave me! In the beginning it wasn't working, but it was because history is supposed to be enabled. Now it's working fine, as IE does! Chrome's add-on works a bit differently, I can only save files, but I'll figure something out! Anyway...thank you! :)