# Angularjs example not working in firefox

Tags: angularjs

Am practicing basic angularjs app. It is working in IE 11 but not in firefox 33.1

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\mallik\ch\jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\mallik\ch\angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="app">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open local folder from different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408031/open-local-folder-from-different-browsers)

Comment: Install a local server. Don't even try to access the files through the filesystem.

Comment: Try to use the latest version of jquerry (2.1.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not have any module, your module should be null by default ie change **ng-app=""**.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can also write just ng-app

Answer (score 0):

In firefox when script src is referred with absolute path it fails in recognizing the files properly. Try to change it to Relative Path, it will work.

```
Absolute path:C:\Users\Mallik\Desktop\mallik\ch\angular.min.js
```

Assuming the html file is in mallik folder

```
Relative path: ../ch/angular.min.js
```

Try this it should work.