# Create a link in Chrome to open a local file structure in IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

Our company has an intranet. And for some of our resources there is a link to a local file structure so everyone can access it. (example: file:\name\file\text.txt)

This works great on IE but Chrome is becoming more and more popular. After researching this, Chrome does not allow access to a local file structure for security reasons.

1. Is there a way to force Chrome (globally, not per computer) to allow access to a local file structure link?

or

2. Can you create a link that requests the user to open it in IE?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links

Comment: Roman - What code do you need to see?

Comment: epascarello - Thank you. I read that question. It had been a while since it had been updated so I had hoped there was something new I was unaware of.