# Open local files(file://) using Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have an page with some forms. All the links work fine in IE. They open in a new tab nicely when the hyperlink is click by the user; however, I realized that when Chrome is use the link doesn't open. I keep clicking but nothing opens. The only way of opening the file is copying the hyperlink, opening a new tab in Chrome, paste and go.

```
<a href="FILE:\\outsideserver\files\shared\form1.pdf" target="_blank">Form1</a>
```

Is this something that browser do? Because I tried it with FireFox and doesn't work either?
It there a way of going around? without installing anything in the browser? Because my user loves Chrome. 
Thank you in advanced for the responses.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links - you can't open file links unless the page is it's self a local file, for security. There is an extension mentioned in the link that might work around your issue.

Comment: This worked for me in Chrome: 
<a href="file://outsideserver/share/file.pdf" target="_blank">Form1</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access to files outside your server or "SandBox", sandbox include the files that user push to the browser or to your server.

If the access from browser to a pc files from web pages was possible, it would be a security problem.

Comment: Is it possible to access a pdf / text file that users drag and drop on a browser? Is this case considered as "sandbox" ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If your user is uploading files at your app this is inside your sandbox.

Comment: what if the user is not uploading, the user just uses chrome to open a local pdf file. and, on that tab, there is my chrome extension, do u know if I can access the file using my chrome extension?

Comment: @Jun711 Yes, you can, in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you can't with your approach and more importantly *you shouldn't*. Chrome behavior is in fact the right behavior and it protects you from having malicious users and/or scripts accessing your local resources.

The `FILE` protocol will access local or defined network *named* resources which will not be available to a remote user that visits the same page. In other words, you may have `outsideserver` mapped as a network resource/drive but someone else will not *(This does not apply to IPs)*

Here's what you can do:

- Move the code to a server side script(php, asp, etc) and stream the file back out. Found a quick example here on SO. I did not verify it though. [Streaming a large file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914912/streaming-a-large-file-using-php)
- Install a webserver on `outsideserver` and map a new site to the `shared` folder. You can then reference it via http (http://outsideserver.com/form1.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below extension for chrome. It will work.

[Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld/)

Below both options are working and tested.

```
<a href="\\server\folder\">Link 2</a>

<a href="file:///C:/folder/test.txt">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: thanks. but this is only for clicking!?? am I right? -----------------  do you know anything better?  I want some background passive extension that just enable accessing file:///

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old but the issue remains in 2023 - *the inability to view file:/// links in browsers w/out manual/user interaction*. My use case may be rare but here is my poor man's workaround if anyone wants to use:
https://gist.github.com/cemerson/cb2da58243837b41b4aaa4541a2380f3
*(Code is fast and sloppy so feel free to clean up)*

Basically it's just a simple HTML page that takes a querystring value of the target file path and it gives the user a way to grab the path URL and/or the file:/// to paste/view themselves in the browser. Having the ability to get a working HTTPS URL that pointed to a local/shared drive file was my primary need/objective and this works for now.