# Create external link in GitLab Flavored Markdown

Tags: gitlab

Is there anyway to link to an external file (non http url) in GitLab Flavored Markdown?

- e.g. HTML equivalent would be `<a href="file:///my/file/path">link text</a>`
- e.g. MediaWiki equivalent would be `[[file:///my/file/path link text]]`

Comment: The [sanitation filter](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#ANCHOR_SCHEMES-constant) used by GitLab seems to filter out any file:// links / unsupported anchor schemes.

Comment: That actually really clears it up.  I wonder if they'd accept a pull-request modifying that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file://` protocol is not included in the [sanitation filter whitelist](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#ANCHOR_SCHEMES-constant) referenced by gitlab in the [documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/markdown/markdown.md#inline-html).

You could manually edit `embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/markdown.rb` in your gitlab installation, add the protocol to the whitelist yourself and restart gitlab after that to apply the changes (just insert the line with the leading `+`):

```
  whitelist = HTML::Pipeline::SanitizationFilter::WHITELIST
  whitelist[:attributes][:all].push('class', 'id')
  whitelist[:elements].push('span')
+ whitelist[:protocols]['a']['href'] = ['file'].concat(whitelist[:protocols]['a']['href'])

  # Remove the rel attribute that the sanitize gem adds, and remove the
  # href attribute if it contains inline javascript
```

but this is probably not the best idea, because it will cause occasional headaches when upgrading the gitlab installation.

And the desired `file://` links will still not open as expected without additional configuration steps or addon installations on the client side (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087894/993388)).

Comment: Never knew Chrome wouldn't link to local file links.  I was going to try this until I read that.. I don't think I can convince people in my office to all install a browser extension. :)  Thanks a lot for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

The normal markdown hyperlink syntax should work: `[file description](file:///test/location/file)`

Comment: I had no luck with this. It treats it like a relative url, e.g. ```http://myBaseUrl:9090/software/proj/blob/master/file:///test/location/file```

Comment: In MediaWiki, file links are explicitly disabled by default (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FileLink). I bet the same is true for GitLab markdown.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't able to find anything to this effect.  In fact, the most relevant thing google returns searching for "gitlab markdown enable file link extension" is this page. :( @Geoff

Comment: I should note that the file paths I was trying to add aren't relative to the web-directory, but fully absolute paths (mostly on shares on other computers)