# Link to physical dir in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

On my mvc view I put a href which looks like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href = "file:///E:\Downloads">Open files dir</a>
```

But for some reason it gets converted to:

```
<a target="_self" href = "LocalExplorer:E:\Downloads">Open files dir</a>
```

and nothing works. What's that about and how can I open directory in browser (directory is accessible, if I try to do the same from the regular web page, not mvc, it works)

Comment: Sure this isn't a matter of a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl?hl=en-US) hijacking your links? `LocalExplorer` isn't the go-to protocol for local file access.

Comment: @BradChristie, yes, I completely forgot about that extension. Now whn it's off, link stays the same, but still nothing happens. Direct link doesn't work at all, and javascript opens just blank page

Comment: @KorsaR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links