# Problems with Chrome in “--allow-file-access-from-files” mode

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to access a file on a shared drive from my application in Chrome. I know there is the --allow-file-access-from-files flag, and I've tried this to no avail. Here are the links I've tried on stackoverflow:

[Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

[How to launch html using Chrome at “--allow-file-access-from-files” mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)

I can't get “--allow-file-access-from-files” or the LocalLinks Chrome extension to work. Is there another setting I have to change? Has this been disabled? I'm running Chrome version 51.0.2704.106 if that makes a difference.

Comment: You use both "application" and "extension" in this question. Which one do you actually mean? And what kind of access are you expecting?

Comment: Hi, I've built a web application on my server (it's not local) and basically from that application I'm trying to access the shared drive.

I only tried an extension "LocalLinks" to fix the local file access problem.

I'm expecting the file to open in windows with the correct program.

Comment: Just want to confirm, are you trying to access local computer files with your Chrome extension?

Comment: No. I'm trying to access files on a shared drive.