# File:// protocol is not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So what we are wanting to do is either type in a path like:   N:/Networkdrive/myfiles/work.doc

or be able to drag a file into the area and the system save the path:  N:/Networkdrive/myfiles/work.doc

Think of having files on a network drive or a shared drive that everyone uses and being able to put in the path to that file so that the person completing the task, will be able to click on the link and get to the  file.

we are add file:///N:/Networkdrive/myfiles/work.doc in href then i have to click this link then its still showing same page its not going to link page and i have add http:// in front of file:// then its going new tab but its remove Colon in (file///N:\networkdrive\myfiles\work.doc)

```
Not allowed to load local resource:
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links). In short, you can't open file:// links unless it's a local html file, you can work around it with custom extensions or custom browsers.

Comment: its not working because we are click this (file://N:\networkdrive\myfiles\work.doc) still showing this msg in console  **Not allowed to load local resource:file://N:\networkdrive\myfiles\work.doc** if i have add http:// in front of file then url open but url is removed colon  example show url (file///N:\networkdrive\myfiles\work.doc)

Comment: what transfer protocol do you use?

Comment: i have used **file:///**