# How can I use link to local files in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am creating the web application task manager that use links to local files.

When I use links like this in Firefox it opens the link in the local application correctly (in MS OneNote):

```
<a href="onenote:///D:\DESKTOP\@СПРАВ\OneNoteФайлы\IT_Work\ПРОЕКТЫ.one#Текущие%20цели&section-id={F27F371C-EF84-4F6F-BEB2-3963D9CD520B}&page-id={EE5B3FA8-57C3-449F-A2D0-2793F389C291}&object-id={B27E87CF-69CD-062A-3823-7653AC9DDFC4}&17">Ссылка на абазц</a>
```

But I can do the same in Chrome.

How can I fix it?

Maybe with some security setting for browser or website or chrome extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Google Chrome open local links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links)

Comment: I think you should add a `click` listener and call chrome.tabs.create({url: event.target.href}) for such links.