# Cant open local file by Chrome or Edge for Japanese environment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to develop HTML base editor equipped with browsing local files function.
I know basically that is restricted by browser to open local files.
However I found out some method doing this activity.
using path begin from "localexplorer://" it works perfect for English path name.
But when I use Japanese folder name or file name it becomes error.
I tried to convert SJIS format that file names but this is not work.
Here is code.

```
[![error[![\]\[1\]][1]][1]][1]url = 'localexplorer:' + event.target.innerText;
            array = str2array(url);
            sjis_array = Encoding.convert(array, "SJIS", "UNICODE");
            sjis= Encoding.codeToString(sjis_array); 
            window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: "it becomes error" ... what is the error?

Comment: Probably the File API can handle the Japanese file name.  Refer to the File API page on MDN.

Comment: error is "Local Explorer Set Up" File or Folder not found:

Comment: MDN no mention about this Local Explorer so any how I cant find out the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [browser security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security), javascript is only allowed to run in the sandbox, you cannot read or write arbitrary files:

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to
> deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the Web. Browser
> authors minimize this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run
> in a sandbox in which they can only perform Web-related actions, not
> general-purpose programming tasks like creating files.

If the user selects a file via `<input type="file">`, you could try to read the content of the file through `FileReader API`, like this case: [How to open a local disk file with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

If you need to interact with files on the user's local device or a user-accessible network file system, you can try to use the File System Access API. And this must be done in a `secure context`, and must be called from within a user gesture. You can also read this article to learn more about it：[The File System Access API: simplifying access to local files](https://web.dev/file-system-access/).

Comment: Actually what I want to do is described in this site see comment 12, I need a open <a> tag link for local files it not requires input type. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links>

Comment: Well, if you are using [Local Explorer-File Manager on web browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl), it does not work when the path or file name contains Unicode characters. For more details, you could refer to [LOCAL EXPLORER - USER GUIDE](https://www.vnprodev.com/browser-extensions/local-explorer-install.php?thanks#userguide).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, I solved this issue by Forefox plug in extensions, it seems like chrome did not support this functions even if there is plug in extensions.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29891646)