# Local links such as file:// or \10.0.0.1 in markdown documents do not work properly. Is there a workaround or workaround?

Tags: docsify

This may be elementary, but please let me know.
Local links such as `file://` or `\\10.0.0.1` in markdown documents do not work properly. Is there a workaround or workaround?
I really need this kind of functionality.

```
Example:  
[link1](file://10.0.0.1/example.html)  
[link2](\\10.0.0.1\example.html)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the docsify problem
You can see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123202/12099167)
the file links are not allowed to be rendered in browser for security reasons.
and also you link is wrong it should be like this
link1
but still it won't work as it is a security issue and most browser don't support it and even if they support may be they have bug or they are not trustable.

for the solution i can't say anything because i don't know why do you need local file link in your website you don't know if the client have such file or not.
may be you can give the scenario and we can find the solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34400690)