Html file with jquery snippet to open local/NFS path works if opened directly in browser, but gives error if hosted via lightweight server
I have a lightweight html file with a jquery snippet to open a new browser tab with a local/NFS directory or folder path.
This works when I open the html file directly in my browser (edge/chrome)


But when I use a webserver like 'serve' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to host the html page on localhost, the jquery snippet fails and gives me an error - failed to load local resource.


Is there an underlying cross-origin issue due to which this happens?

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123202/1427878: "You can't link to file:/// from an HTML document that is not itself a file:/// for security reasons."
