# An URL to a Windows shared folder

Tags: html, url, networking, share, file-uri

Is there a way to incorporate a *working* link to a Windows shared folder into an HTML page?  E.g. a link to `\\server\folder\path`?

For simplicity, let's say the page will be opened on a Windows machine (and on the same intranet where the `server` is located, of course.)

I've tried a few tricks with `file://` scheme, but none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

1. You need to escape the slashes.
2. Browser security.

Explanation:

1. I checked one of mine, I have the pattern:

   ```
   <a href="file://///server01\fshare\dir1\dir2\dir3">useful link </a>
   ```

   Please note that we ended up with 5 slashes after the protocol (`file:`)
2. Firefox will try to prevent cross site scripting. My solution was to modify **prefs.js** in the profile directory.  You will add two lines:

   ```
   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://mysite.company.org");
   ```

Comment: Yes, browser security is the issue.  But I don't know if target browser is Firefox.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to a similar question, where IE should work, Firefox can be adjusted, but other major browsers block this. [stackoverflow.com/questions/855614](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614)

Comment: Do I need to configure browser's settings first? Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

File protocol URIs are like this

```
file://[HOST]/[PATH]
```

that's why you often see file URLs like this (3 slashes)

```
file:///c:\path\...
```

So if the host is `server01`, you want

```
file://server01/folder/path....
```

This is according to the [wikipedia page on file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and checks out with .NET's `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to go further then javascript/html facilities - I would use the apache web server to represent your directory listing via http.

If this solution is appropriate. these are the steps:

1. download apache hhtp server from one of the mirrors http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi
2. unzip/install (if msi) it to the directory e.g C:\opt\Apache (the instruction is for windows)
3. map the network forlder as a local drive on windows (\server\folder to let's say drive H:)
4. open conf/httpd.conf file
5. make sure the next line is present and not commented

   LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
6. Add directory configuration

`<Directory "H:/path">`

`Options +Indexes`

`AllowOverride None`

`Order allow,deny`

`Allow from all`

`</Directory>`
7. Start the web server and make sure the directory listingof the remote folder is available by http. hit localhost/path
8. use a frame inside your web page to access the listing

**What is missed:** 
 1. you mignt need more fancy configuration for the host name, refer to Apache Web Server docs. Register the host name in DNS server

1. the mapping to the network drive might not work, i did not check. As a posible resolution - host your web server on the same machine as smb server.

Answer (score -2):

This depend on how you want to incorporate it.
The scenario
1. click on a link
2. explorer window popped up

```
<a href="\\server\folder\path" target="_blank">click</a>
```

If there is a need in a fancy UI - then it will barely serve as a solution.

Comment: I think this won't work unless the HTML itself is loaded with `file://` URI scheme.  At least it doesn't work with the WebKit-based Chrome.