# File URLs or how to open folder from URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have several users on an intranet and all have a mapped drive to server (E:).
All users are on Win7 and use FireFox. 
I have used XAMPP on the server to allow users access to MySQL files using PHP.
They currently use windows explorer to open a folder on (E:) so save/modify files (jpgs, docs etc.).
I want to put a link in the html to open this folder for them.

I've spent some time researching this with varying amounts of success and I have found out that this may have security issues such as...

*A web application does not have access to the local machine's filesystem*

but these are all clients accessing the same server on a local intranet.

I can type...

```
file:///C:/MyFolder/MySubFolder/
```

in my browser address bar which opens a page with a directory listing of the files in the sub folder. Not ideal but half way to a solution!

But the script below does not work...

```
window.open("file:///C:/MyFolder/MySubFolder/");
```

Can this be done?

Comment: please have a look over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796215/an-url-to-a-windows-shared-folder

Comment: here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder

Comment: I spent a few hours looking at some of these suggestions and just got more confused.       Either it can't be done or I may need to change FF configs.    It would be great if someone could just post a fiddle or some kind of example to show me how to use     window.open("file:///C:/MyFolder/MySubFolder/");       If I can see this working I should be OK

Answer (score 0):

you `path` would be

```
window.open("http://localhost/MyFolder/MySubFolder/");
```

or

```
window.open("http://IP/MyFolder/MySubFolder/");
```

use `absolute path` for this

Comment: Can you please explain how your suggestions should be modified to simulate ' window.open("file:///C:/MyFolder/MySubFolder/"); ' ?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will work if the link is in its own mangled form using five slashes (`file://///C:/MyFolder/MySubFolder/`) **and** the user has [disabled the security restriction on `file:` links in a page served over HTTP](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work).

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder/855658#855658) post for more info