# Open shared file path using window.open in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have tried with below code to open a shared folder file through Javascript:

```
window.open("file:///xxx.xxx.xx.xx(Shared IP Address)/Images/yyyy.pdf");
```

But it is opening a new window with a blank page. How do I achieve this?

Comment: May be this SO post could be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5796952/5104101 and this one too http://stackoverflow.com/a/855658/5104101