# Description Setter Plugin - add hyper link to a network folder

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Description Setter Plugin for adding an hyper link to a network folder.
In *Set build description* --> *Description*, I've added the following:

```
<a href="\\server\folder1\folder2\folder3">[Release]</a>
```

When job is finished, I can see the link but when pressing it, nothing happens.
If I copy the path to browser's url, it will open the relevant path (but via Jenkins it doesn't).

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

** With a custom HTML page it works.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796215/an-url-to-a-windows-shared-folder.

Comment: Via Jenkins - Description Setter plugin, it does not work. I've tried all options:
file://///server/path/
file://server/path/

Comment: Are you sure that these links will work in your browser? Maybe try it with a custom HTML page first to make sure that it will actually open such local links at all.

Comment: With a custom HTML page it works.

Comment: So then compare the output in the HTML of Jenkins an your HTML page. Do they really match? Are you loading your HTML page from a `file:///` URL or via HTTP? Maybe this has an influence as well. As well as your browser (this information should be added to the thread..)

Comment: Actually I'm not loading an html page, I'm using Jenkins 'Description Setter Plugin' (also tried with Rich Text Publisher Plugin).

Answer (score 4):

You are either using Plain Text or Safe HTML formatter.
Unfortunately the only HTML formatter than can parse the file links is the *anything-goes formatter*, which is very unsafe - javascripts are also allowed, and anyone can add harmful code to their user's description for example.
To use it, download the *anything-goes-formatter* plugin, go to

> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> Markup Formatter

change to *Allows arbitrary HTML includin [sic] JavaScript (UNSAFE)*.