# Is it possible to link a file from shared drive on public facing website?

Tags: iis-7, file-sharing

I have searched for the answer to this question, and have found some similar results, but most seem to be interested in linking a file on an internal website (such as this one: [An URL to a Windows shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796215/an-url-to-a-windows-shared-folder)). I am hoping to find a way to link a file on a public facing site.

On my windows server, I have several drives - for the ease of this, let's call them C:, D:, and E:

- C: is, of course, the OS.
- I have a file share for internal users (those on the same network) on E:. I have the file share location shared internally as \server\data.
- I have a public facing website (through IIS) on D:. Let's say the website is located at D:\Website, with the default page being D:\Website\index.html.

Is it possible to create a link on the website that points to files on the E: drive? Like file://server/data/file.txt? Or would it be easier to move the website to the same directory as the file share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible , but \\server (Windows UNC port 445) is a port that was abused and is blocked by many ISP's for almost a decade now.

Your "public" most likely will not have access

file:/// will not work either , as to the user, that means the persons local machine

what you can do is create a virtual directory to your drive or network share in IIS and make sure in iis (optionally can you can enable use directory browsing)

ftp:// is also a possibility as well and what i think you should look into

Comment: Is it possible to create a site in IIS and point to internally that way? Or would it be easier to just move the website to the same drive as the share?

Comment: "what you can do is create a virtual directory in IIS and make sure in iis you allow directory browsing" - I'll give this a shot and see where it gets me

Comment: try ftp:// i think this is what you want

Comment: I have the FTP server running, but I didn't think about linking it that way. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Bingo - ftp was definitely what I wanted. That's one of those things that it was so simple, I should kick myself for not thinking of it. Oh well. Live and learn. Thank you!