# Opening a directory from Chrome using file://

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087894/can-google-chrome-open-local-links) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder) it seems it wasn't possible due to security issues, but these are old posts.

I am guessing it still isn't possible, as when I click on the link nothing seems to happen. What I want is for the folder to open. Does anybody know if there are any workarounds other than installing extensions?

I'm using Chrome `Version 31.0.1650.57 m`

The HTML for the link is:

```
<a href="D:\2013_1123" title="D:\2013_1123">D:\2013_1123</a>
```

Chrome converts this into a `file://` protocol url automatically.

The Url for the webpage is: `http://localhost:50584/` - so is running on http space

My website will run as an intranet and the directory will be a shared network drive if that helps at all.

Comment: "Doesn't work for me" isn't very descriptive. What version of Chrome are you running? What is your current file system setup? 

Maybe try posting a code snippet, the current output, or any error messages you're getting. All of the above might get you a more definitive answer than anybody's speculation.

As an aside, this works for me on Chrome v32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work from any http(s) context,

however, if your pages are all static content, you can have the bookmark point to your file:// index.html and then it will work.