# can't create hyper link HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am creating layout. I included hyperlink but it doesn't work. I wrote my 'href' in this format.

```
href="C:/Users/Dmitry/PycharmProjects/save&edit/templates/form_action.html"
```

Of course I took it in  tags. After clicking on this link it doesn't react.

Comment: Don't you want to link to a web location rather than somewhere on your disk?

Comment: Try `<a href="file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/1.html">Link</a>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the ways to make an html link open a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<a href="C:\Users\Dmitry\PycharmProjects\save&edit\templates\form_action.html">My Link</a>
```

Comment: fixed defined relative path and it works <a href="templates/form_action.html">My Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

Defined relative path `<a href="templates/form_action.html">My Link</a>`. Finally it works.