# Create links to Shared folder MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a possibility in MediaWiki to create an external link to a 
windows network folder like

```
               \\server\folder1 ????
```

It does not work using syntax of external or internal links ;-(

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://mediawiki.org/wiki/UNC_links

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$wgUrlProtocols`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols) (in `LocalSettings.php`) do define what url protocols MediaWiki should recognize. Adding `file`, like this: `$wgUrlProtocols[] = 'file://';` You should then be able to link to your network folder, e.g. `[file://///server/folder Click here to go to folder]` .

For further discussion about how to create that url, and what browsers will actually let you follow it, see [What are the ways to make an html link open a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder#855658)

This setting will also make your network folder show up on `Special:LinkSearch`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added as you mentioned. It is appearing as link but not opening on clicking that link

Comment: Only some browsers will actually allow you to open such a link, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder#855658

Answer (score -1):

`$wgUrlProtocols` is the array.
To add `file://` to `$wgUrlProtocols` in `LocalSettings.php`:

`array_push($wgUrlProtocols, "file://");`