# How to put a space in a sphinx url for windows drive

Tags: windows, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to create a hyperlink to a folder that has a space in it. 
The space is removed because of the way rst is processing the link.

Unfortunately I can't change the name of the folder because I'm not the owner.

This was solved below by adding `%20` but now there is a second problem:

The path should be "file:///T:/my_path/A&B Tools".

It can also be represented as "\\network.com\my_path\A&B Tools".

```
* First link   `hyperlink-name-1`_
* Second link  `hyperlink-name-2`_

.. _hyperlink-name-1: file:///T:/my_path/A&B%20Tools
.. _hyperlink-name-2: \\\\network.com\\my_path\\A&B%20Tools
```

The first link works when I map `network.com` to `T`:

Edit:

Thanks to Steve I looked at the html I see when I use second link. The windows path starting with \ doesn't seem to work properly. I think this is a windows interpretation of the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try URL-encoding the space:

```
* A link  `hyperlink-name`_

.. _hyperlink-name: file://my_path/A&B%20Tools
```

**EDIT**

And now with your example above, Sphinx generates the following HTML:

```
<ul class="simple">
<li>First link   <a class="reference external" href="file:///T:/my_path/A&amp;B%20Tools">hyperlink-name-1</a></li>
<li>Second link  <a class="reference external" href="\\network.com\my_path\A&amp;B%20Tools">hyperlink-name-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I suspect you copy-pastad an invisible character (gremlin) into your .rst file.  I noticed that you mixed examples in your question, too: `A&B Tools` vs. `M&S Tools`.  I'd slow down and check all my assumptions.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I've updated the question above.

Comment: Updated, and thanks for the tip. Now that I look at the html I see when I use the windows path with \\network.com\ it doesn't like the use of %20 and maybe the &amp;. The file:/// link works perfect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doesn't like". But if my answer is correct, please accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Steve for helping me. I needed five slashes  `file://///server01/my_path/` as shown here:

[What are the ways to make an html link open a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Five slashes! Who woulda thunk it?