# From web browser to user PC [concept] (Windows, ASP. NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a intranet ASP .NET MVC Application with basic authentification.

App is a collection of local resources, example list of folders. User does find folder on portal and want open in explorer

Intranet work with AD.

On first stage I need with a link/button in webbrowser

- a) open local folder on PC in explorer
- b) open shared folder in intranet in explorer

but

- a) is not possible
- b) [with many limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder)

I have only one solution

- 1. Create a service and install on each user PC
- 2. Sending from ASP .NET application command to service

but

1. Not like idea with the service on every pc
2. How to link web site user to user pc?

Question

May be there are more easy way to send command to intranet / AD user PC

Comment: What's the overall goal here? Is the user expected to interact with this window? In what way(s)? In general, it's not going to happen so trying to create a flow that *doesn't* involve opening this window in the first place is the direction I'd be expending my efforts. (Also, the service idea itself doesn't really help since services run in session 0 with no UI access, isolated from any user sessions)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever App is a collection of local resources, example list of folders. User does find folder on portal and want open in explorer

Comment: Sorry, but your question is incredibly hard to understand.