# Save excel file containing links as html, and these links open in file explorer, not web browser

Tags: html, excel

I have an excel sheet with links to local folders. To make it more device "friendly" I save it as html. All is fine, but the links open on the web browser, not windows file explorer.
I know that html does not open aps, but I do not know if opening a local folder with windows file explorer is considered an app, or I miss something.

Excel: `=hyperlink("c:\testfolder")`

Of course another suggestion on the matter is welcome...

Comment: Find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855614/what-are-the-ways-to-make-an-html-link-open-a-folder

Comment: Sorry, not found. Maybe I was not clear. I use excel, and save the sheet as html file. I am not familiar with html code (so as to intervene on the created html file).

Answer (score 0):

add `file://` to the link

```sh
=hyperlink("file://c:\testfolder")
```

Comment: Sorry, nothing. The html still opens the directory in browser, not fil explorer

Comment: It may be to do with your local configuration, as this worked for me..

Comment: Care to elaborate? What to search for?